# print list as output

Tags: python

I want to convert num1 and num2 to a list and print it,any inputs on how this can be done?

```
num1 = 12345
num2 = 34266 73628


print num1
print num2

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

['12345']
['34266','73628']
```

Comment: Cast to str and Use split function

Comment: `num = 34266 73628` is not valid python syntax. What do you mean by this line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `num1` and `num2` are both strings (otherwise you have a syntax error). You can use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> num1 = '12345'
>>> num2 = '34266 73628'
>>> num1.split()
['12345']
>>> num2.split()
['34266', '73628']
```

Answer (score 0):

Make them strings, so you can use split, and then turn them into integers!!

```
num1 = '12345'
num2 = '34266 73628'
def func(number):
    num = number.split()
    return [int(i) for i in num]

>>> func(num1)
[12345]
>>> 
>>> func(num2)
[34266, 73628]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n1 = '1234 456' #note the single quotes
n2 = '567 879'

def foo(num):
  return num.split()

foo(n1)
foo(n2)
```

And the output:

```
['1234', '456']
['567', '789']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = '12345'
num2 = '12345 67890'
#Note: Both must be strings

#Option 1(Recommended)
print num1.split()
print num2.split()

#Option 2
import shlex
print shlex.split(num2)

#Option 3
import re
print re.split(' ', num2)

#If the array needs to be of ints:
result1 = [int(item) for item in num1.split()]
result2 = [int(item) for item in num2.split()]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
num1 = [12345]
num2 = [34266, 73628]


print num1
print num2
```

Comment: The question is how to turn the string into a list.

Comment: That's not at all clear, since the original post is not even valid python. I took my best guess at what the OP might have actually wanted.